# problems on our organization-id (not happening with another organization)

Tags: apigee

We are not able to call any of our APIs on our organization, we are receiving classification_failure on each API call even the testing ones that are related to weather.yahoo.com etc.. 
each time we open the API proxy the message the following message is displayed (No server entry found with ID 1c53328c-57b6-4f69-bdf0-ce4b39e64ef3) .

we had an increase of the traffic on our apis , is it possilble that apiggee closed the api because they monitored high volume of traffic.

I created another organization it is all working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed this along to our support team.  It may be a hardware problem.  (Just saw this problem with a colleague and he got it resolved.  Check yours to see if it was related)

You can also email help@apigee.com with details about your org and traffic spike.